# binary file to csv file multiple variables

Tags: c, csv, binaryfiles

I am trying to write a program to take input from a binary file full of data points of alternating Altitude and Airspeed numbers and convert that to a csv file.  The data needs to be byteswapped from big endian to little endian as well.  When I run my code I get the same number for all of them and it is not the right number either for printing out, and it will not print anything but weird greek letters to the csv file.  Can somebody tell me what I am doing wrong?

Code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
union byteswap
{
    char c_num[4];
    float f_num;
};
char temp;
union byteswap data;
int size;
int i;
struct time
{
    //float time_s;
    float Alt_ft;
    float AS_knots;
    //float mach_number;
};
struct time time_pt;
FILE *fp;
fp = fopen("C:\\Users\\daxon\\eclipse-workspace\\Flight-Data-Proj\\Alt_AS.dat", "r+b");

FILE *csv;
csv = fopen("C:\\Users\\daxon\\eclipse-workspace\\Flight-Data-Proj\\Flight-Data.csv", "w+");

if (fp== NULL)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Data file would not open");
    return(-1);
}

fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
size=ftell(fp);
fprintf(stdout, "The size of the file is %d\n", size);
fseek(fp,0,SEEK_CUR);

    for (i = 0; i<= feof(fp); i++)
    {
        fread(&time_pt, 8, 1, fp);
        fprintf(stdout, "Uswapped is %d\n", time_pt);

        //byte swap
        temp = data.c_num[0];
        data.c_num[0] = data.c_num[3];
        data.c_num[3]= temp;
        temp = data.c_num[1];
        data.c_num[1] = data.c_num[2];
        data.c_num[2]= temp;

        printf("Alt is %f,  AS is %f\n", time_pt.Alt_ft, time_pt.AS_knots);
        fwrite(&time_pt.Alt_ft, 4, 1, csv);
        fwrite(&time_pt.AS_knots, 4, 1, csv);
    }

fclose(fp);
fclose(csv);
fprintf(stdout, "Done reading files\n");
return 0;
```

}

output:

The size of the file is 143208
Uswapped is 1986426061

Alt is 1168552030029638100000000000000000.000000,  AS is 0.000000

Uswapped is 1986426061

Alt is 1168552030029638100000000000000000.000000,  AS is 0.000000

Uswapped is 1986426061

Alt is 1168552030029638100000000000000000.000000,  AS is 0.000000

Uswapped is 1986426061

Alt is 1168552030029638100000000000000000.000000,  AS is 0.000000

Uswapped is 1986426061

Alt is 1168552030029638100000000000000000.000000,  AS is 0.000000

Uswapped is 1986426061

Alt is 1168552030029638100000000000000000.000000,  AS is 0.000000

Uswapped is 1986426061

Alt is 1168552030029638100000000000000000.000000,  AS is 0.000000

Uswapped is 1986426061

Alt is 1168552030029638100000000000000000.000000,  AS is 0.000000

Uswapped is 1986426061

Alt is 1168552030029638100000000000000000.000000,  AS is 0.000000

Uswapped is 1986426061

Alt is 1168552030029638100000000000000000.000000,  AS is 0.000000

Uswapped is 1986426061

Alt is 1168552030029638100000000000000000.000000,  AS is 0.000000

Uswapped is 1986426061

Alt is 1168552030029638100000000000000000.000000,  AS is 0.000000

Uswapped is 1986426061

Alt is 1168552030029638100000000000000000.000000,  AS is 0.000000

Uswapped is 1986426061

Alt is 1168552030029638100000000000000000.000000,  AS is 0.000000

Uswapped is 1986426061

Alt is 1168552030029638100000000000000000.000000,  AS is 0.000000

Uswapped is 1986426061

Alt is 1168552030029638100000000000000000.000000,  AS is 0.000000

Uswapped is 1986426061

Alt is 1168552030029638100000000000000000.000000,  AS is 0.000000

Done reading files

I have tried multiple ways to split the file into two struct variables and this has gotten me the closest.

Edit: Now it only repeats the for loop 17 times before completing when the file is much bigger.

Comment: What are those libraries you included? Please give it some format, and paste the libraries included.

Comment: Some problems are: you don't check the return value of `read` so we don't know if it works. The `size` you get is the number of bytes in the file, not the number of `float` values or structs, so the for-loop will run too many times. You also read into `time_pt` but byte swap `data` which is a different variable. You also seem to read 4 bytes (1 `float`) but then use 2 `floats` from `time_pt`.

Comment: I have tried following your suggestions but it is still not the right output.  The first data set is altitude is 32500 and airspeed is 0.

Comment: I wonder why people use C for csv processing while there's Python & AWK.

Comment: @KarimManaouil, wtf????  Why not writing operating systems in python or awk, or compilers, for example?  In the beginning was C...

Comment: @LuisColorado i don't think CSV  could be part of an OS or a compiler. AWK was just invented and improved for that kind of thing. Then why not using it ?

Comment: @KarimManaouil CSV allow values to be double quote escaped, backslash escaped, allow space before and after commas.  Although the language is regular (can be matched by a regexp) is better to fully parse it.  But for simple CSVs, you can suffice with awk.  Anyway, if you prefer to write python code, then good luck, but don't be critic with C in a forum tagged C, it's you who are not in the proper forum.  Let's solve our problems with the tools we select.